# How to remove an unnecessary int allocation when converting a two dimensional into a one dimensional array?

Tags: java

Whenever I want to convert an `int[][]` into an `int[]` array, I follow the procedure shown underneath.

```
final int[][] source = new int[3][3];
final int[] array = new int[9];
// I allocate an int that represents the current index of the int[] array.
int index = 0;
// Afterwards I iterate over the `int[][]` array.
for (int x = 0; x < 3; x++)
{
    for (int y = 0; y < 3; y++)
    {
         array[++index] = source[x][y];
    }
}
```

The code does the job, but I want to know if there is a better solution for my problem that effectively eliminates the `index` variable and even enhances the efficiency of my code.

Comment: Depends. Is the 2d array fixed dimensions? If so: yes, we can use arrayCopy to make this *a lot* better. If not, we can still do things more efficiently but not as efficient if the 2nd dimension is fixed.

Comment: Let's suppose that the 2 dimensional array is indeed fixed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do this with a single loop:

```
for (int x = 0; x < width; x++) {
  System.arraycopy(twoDimensionalArray[x], 0, oneDimensionalArray, x*height, height);
}
```

Comment: Another question: is `System.arraycopy` less efficient (performance wise) than the answer posted by Probie?

Comment: @ToxicTV if anything it is more efficient, not less.

Comment: I just want to know, due to reason that the loop in my program runs roughly ten thousand times.

Comment: arrayCopy is _insanely_ efficient. It is a straight-up memory copy without any iteration.

Comment: One thing I still don't understand: what is `y` in your answer?

Comment: You say that you only need one for loop, but it would seem as if you still need two of them.

Comment: @ToxicTV you only need one *explicit* loop.

Comment: What does an _explicit_ loop mean exactly?

Comment: I would love it if you would append a small example to your answer!

Comment: Small example of what? This is all the code that is necessary.

Comment: But what do I replace the variable `y` with?

Comment: An explicit loop is one which you actually write in the loop. `System.arraycopy` may contain loops, but you don't see them in this code: to all intents and purposes, it's just a method invocation like any other; the explicit loop is the `for`.

Comment: @ToxicTV where is the second loop? arrayCopy issues a memory-region copy instruction, there is no "looping through the entries inside the copied portion of the array", the JVM literally just copies an entire memory segment over wholesale by telling the OS to do that for it, based on the fact that it knows how the bytes should align (which it does, because java is type safe, and a type-incompatible arrayCopy is an error)

Comment: Alright, know I understand! I was just wondering what the variable `y` meant in his answer, but he changed it later on into the "height" of the array!

Comment: Also note that if the array is not fixed dimensions, or simply "unknown", then we can assign `width` from `twoDimensionalArray.length`, and `height` inside the loop from `twoDimensionalArray[x].length`, and have things still work. The only tricky part is preallocating a long enough array to copy into (in which case you might need an initial loop that tallies up all the "column" lengths so you can compute the length of the target array)

Answer (score 0):

We can just directly calculate it

```
for (int x = 0; x < width; x++)
{
     for (int y = 0; y < height; y++)
     {
          oneDimensionalArray[x*height+y] = twoDimensionalArray[x][y];
     }
}
```

Comment: why would you do this, just arrayCopy entire secondary arrays?

Comment: The question just asked how to get rid of `index`. It shouldn't really matter, on anything small it won't take long, on anything large hotspot will work its magic.

Comment: the question is how to do things efficiently. Just getting rid of `index` is not really a useful answer for that purpose, it makes things marginally faster, but nowhere near as fast as normal java already allows this to be.

Comment: In the current version of the question, it doesn't even mention the word "efficient", it does explicitly say remove `index`...